# Batch command to schedule multiple servers to shutdown

Tags: scheduled-task, batch-file, batch

Our company is in the middle of a move between buildings.  I've been asked to schedule the majority of our servers to shutdown at midday tomorrow.

They already have a scheduled task for this, which occurred in the past, and occurred once only.

I simply need to update the date and time - they are already running as the local administrator account.

Is there a batch command to alter the date/time for these tasks on multiple servers?

Comment: I'm going to guess that this is Windows, even though the term "batch file" is generic. Please clarify and use appropriate tags.

Answer (score 1):

[schtasks!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

"Enables an administrator to create, delete, query, change, run, and end scheduled tasks on a local or remote computer."

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions posted in this [thread.](https://serverfault.com/questions/17931/what-is-a-good-modern-parallel-ssh-tool) example pssh or clusterssh